# Which approach to determine the size of an object to be placed given the sizes of the existing objects in a scene?

Tags: generative-models, image, object-recognition

I am working on an automated approach to object-based data augmentation. The goal of the approach would be to add a selected object to an existing image. To automate this task, information is needed about the size of the object to be added so that it is coherent with the rest of the scene. I've been looking for works that tackled this issue, but couldn't find any.

I would be grateful if you could share references and possible approaches...

Thanks in advance